# nohup parallel and rsync out of memory error

Tags: rsync, nohup

I have 10TB of data (around 100Million PDFs) that I'm copying from a Centos box to a new Ubuntu box. I created a script copy-pdfs.sh with this

```
parallel -j 10 :::: jobs.txt
```

and started the process using nohup (It's a remote server so I can't easily use the console). This is my command to start the jobs.

```
nohup /home/user/copy-pdfs.sh &
```

My jobs.txt looks something like this, there are about 36000 folders.

```
rsync -avvz --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fug=rw,Fo=r --chown={$owner}:{$group} user@old-server:/pdfs/1 /pdfs/. >> /home/user/progress.log;echo 'folder 1 done' >> /home/user/prog.log
rsync -avvz --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fug=rw,Fo=r --chown={$owner}:{$group} user@old-server:/pdfs/2 /pdfs/. >> /home/user/progress.log;echo 'folder 2 done' >> /home/user/prog.log
rsync -avvz --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fug=rw,Fo=r --chown={$owner}:{$group} user@old-server:/pdfs/3 /pdfs/. >> /home/user/progress.log;echo 'folder 3 done' >> /home/user/prog.log
```

My problem is that this runs fine for up-to 24 hours then stops. My nohup.out simply has:

```
Killed
```

And in syslog I have this:

```
Jan 19 19:08:00 {$server} kernel: [97451.781319] Out of memory: Kill process 9765 (rsync) score 1 or sacrifice child
Jan 19 19:08:00 {$server} kernel: [97451.782165] Killed process 9765 (rsync) total-vm:535628kB, anon-rss:10044kB, file-rss:1500kB
```

The new server is virtual and on the first run it had 4GB RAM. I had a another 4GB assigned to it, and it now has 8GB RAM. This didn't stop the out of memory error happening. I can't see what's causing this error. I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.